# java autosys SocketException "Too many open files"

Tags: java, autosys

Application throws "Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files", then we increased linux file limit.

Now we can start the process manually, but the auto start from autosys still fails, anyone have any idea on why it still fails?

Comment: Probably the setting of the file limit you did are not effecting for the autosys user? Where did you the change?

Comment: we changed /etc/security/limits.conf by root, set: 
*               soft    nofile          16392
*               hard    nofile          65536

Comment: Try to add in the script which executes your Java application an `ulimit -n` and redirect the output into a logfile to check if this setting is not overwritten by the process which starts the script.

Comment: I tried to print unlimit -n before the app starts, it did return much smaller value compared to when I ulimit -n manually. is there anywhere from autosys can override this?

Comment: Maybe this [KB article](http://www.ca.com/us/support/ca-support-online/product-content/knowledgebase-articles/tec600139.aspx) provide the solution.

Comment: thanks SubOptimal. It looks to be the issue! Do you know if I can override this limit again in our process? cos change to linux or autosys takes long time here

Comment: I would say: Decreasing should be possible for non-root user. Increasing would need root permissions. (Answer needs to be verified.)

Answer (score 0):

autosys agent takes defaults limits value's. so create ulimits values for autosys. It will fix the issue.

You have to create /etc/sysconfig/autosys
and then paste in this file ulimit command 
depending on what you want to change
for example ulimit -n 
after that you have to recycle autosys agent

eg:

`# cat /etc/sysconfig/autosys`

`ulimit -n 65538`